# Arduino multiplication error, +ve * +ve becomes -ve

Tags: c, arduino, avr

I am benchmarking different platforms and languages with a simple script that emulates the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). During testing I found that my arduino gets stuck on seed 447 where multiplying int 13121 by three yields -26173.

My initial code was `

```
//made by Hugo K 
//jun 13 2014




void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial)
  {
    ;//wait for serial to connect
  }

}


void loop()
{
  unsigned long starttime;
  starttime = millis();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
  {
    int a = i;
    while (a != 1)
    {
      if (a%2 == 0)
      {
        a = a/2;
      }
      else
      {
        a = (a*3) + 1;
      }
      //Serial.println(a);
    }

  }
  Serial.println(millis() - starttime);
}`
```

And later confirmed by `

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 while(!Serial)
 {
 }

}


void loop()
{
  int i = 13121;
  Serial.println(i *3);

}`
```

Is there something wrong with the atmega microcontroller in there? or is there a problem with int 13121 that upsets traditional multiplication ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the sizeof(int) == 2 in this architecture, the max positive integer is 0x7FFF (32,767), while in your case it's 39363.

Using unsigned int will increase your max to 0xFFFF

Using unsigned long - to 0xFFFFFFFF

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your expectation that `int` is 32 bits. With AVR, [`int` is only *16* bits](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Type_Layout); use `long` if you want 32 bits.

Comment: he needs unsigned long to get 32 bits, 'long' will give him 31

Comment: @OlegGryb `long` is 32 bits ... 1 sign bit and 31 precision bits

Comment: since he's dealing with positive numbers only the max that he can get for 'long' is 0x7FFFFFFF, which is 31 bits, while in the case of unsigned long the max will be 0xFFFFFFFF (32 bit). He'll lose one bit if doesn't use unsigned types.

Comment: do not use `long` if you want 32 bit. whenever you have concrete requirements to a data type made it explicit in the declaration. use `uint32_t`or `int32_t` in this case.